# Android chrome print, how is it set up?

Tags: chrome-for-android, offline, printing

I'm looking to replace a mobile laptop with an Android tablet.

I noticed on my Android 4 phone, in Chrome, there is an option Menu>Print, which lets me generate a PDF, or select a printer. When I choose "All Printers", it says "Searching for printers", and does not list any.

I'm guessing I need to set up a WiFi printer. Or do I need Bluetooth? What should I search for to make sure I get a compatible printer.

Also, can this work without an internet connection? (assuming I managed to cache the page or pull up the page in Chrome) I need to be able to print reliable even in spotty internet.

Answer (score 1):

Some printers come preinstalled with Google Cloud Print capabilities. Check to see if your printer already has Cloud Print: http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/printers.html

If your printer does not support Google Cloud Print, but it supports WiFi printing, you need to install a printer service before you can use WiFi to print. They are available on the Play Store, and you can quickly get a list of them from Settings>Printing. Only printers that support WiFi printing or cloud printing will be compatible.

And, wireless printing will not work without an internet connection, unless you have your phone hard-wired to either your printer or a connected computer.